# Extracting Spot Value from Thermal Image

Tags: r, image-processing, exiftool

I have a FLIR Image from which I want to extract "spot value". The spot value is printed on the image. I found the Thermimage package that I use in R.

This is what I get when I run this:

```
library(Thermimage)
flirsettings("FLIR8655.jpg", exiftoolpath = "installed", camvals = "")


$Info
$Info$ExifToolVersionNumber
[1] 10.62

$Info$FileName
[1] 8655

$Info$Directory
[1] "357-2517"

$Info$FileSize
[1] 74

$Info$FilePermissions
[1] ""

$Info$FileType
[1] ""

$Info$FileTypeExtension
[1] ""

$Info$MIMEType
[1] ""

$Info$JFIFVersion
[1] 1.01

$Info$ExifByteOrder
[1] "-"

$Info$Make
[1] ""

$Info$CameraModelName
[1] 3

$Info$Orientation
[1] ""

$Info$XResolution
[1] 72

$Info$YResolution
[1] 72

$Info$ResolutionUnit
[1] ""

$Info$Software
[1] "3.6.0"

$Info$YCbCrPositioning
[1] ""

$Info$ExposureTime
[1] 150

$Info$ExifVersion
[1] 220

$Info$ComponentsConfiguration
[1] "-"

$Info$SubjectDistance
[1] 1

$Info$FocalLength
[1] 1.8

$Info$ImageTemperatureMax
[1] 311

$Info$ImageTemperatureMin
[1] 296

$Info$FlashpixVersion
[1] 100

$Info$ColorSpace
[1] ""

$Info$ExifImageWidth
[1] 320

$Info$ExifImageHeight
[1] 240

$Info$DigitalZoomRatio
[1] 1

$Info$ImageUniqueID
[1] 7.415218e+19

$Info$Compression
[1] "-"

$Info$ThumbnailOffset
[1] 1894

$Info$ThumbnailLength
[1] 2474

$Info$CreatorSoftware
[1] NA

$Info$Emissivity
[1] 0.95

$Info$ObjectDistance
[1] 1

$Info$ReflectedApparentTemperature
[1] 20

$Info$AtmosphericTemperature
[1] 20

$Info$IRWindowTemperature
[1] 20

$Info$IRWindowTransmission
[1] 1

$Info$RelativeHumidity
[1] 50

$Info$PlanckR1
[1] 11326.43

$Info$PlanckB
[1] 1316.8

$Info$PlanckF
[1] 1.65

$Info$AtmosphericTransAlpha1
[1] 0.006569

$Info$AtmosphericTransAlpha2
[1] 0.01262

$Info$AtmosphericTransBeta1
[1] -0.002276

$Info$AtmosphericTransBeta2
[1] -0.00667

$Info$AtmosphericTransX
[1] 1.9

$Info$CameraTemperatureRangeMax
[1] 150

$Info$CameraTemperatureRangeMin
[1] -10

$Info$CameraTemperatureMaxClip
[1] 180

$Info$CameraTemperatureMinClip
[1] -40

$Info$CameraTemperatureMaxWarn
[1] 150

$Info$CameraTemperatureMinWarn
[1] -10

$Info$CameraTemperatureMaxSaturated
[1] 180

$Info$CameraTemperatureMinSaturated
[1] -60

$Info$CameraModel
[1] 3

$Info$CameraPartNumber
[1] "72003-0303"

$Info$CameraSerialNumber
[1] 720071224

$Info$CameraSoftware
[1] "34.0.0"

$Info$LensModel
[1] 2

$Info$LensPartNumber
[1] NA

$Info$LensSerialNumber
[1] NA

$Info$Isotherm1Color
[1] 100128128

$Info$Isotherm2Color
[1] 100110240

$Info$PaletteMethod
[1] 0

$Info$PaletteStretch
[1] 2

$Info$PaletteFileName
[1] "."

$Info$PaletteName
[1] ""

$Info$Palette
[1] "672-"

$Info$RawThermalImageWidth
[1] 80

$Info$RawThermalImageHeight
[1] 60

$Info$RawThermalImageType
[1] "PNG"

$Info$RawThermalImage
[1] "6352-"

$Info$Real2IR
[1] 1.389537

$Info$OffsetX
[1] -1

$Info$OffsetY
[1] 8

$Info$PiPX1
[1] 0

$Info$PiPX2
[1] 80

$Info$PiPY1
[1] 0

$Info$PiPY2
[1] 60

$Info$EmbeddedImageWidth
[1] 640

$Info$EmbeddedImageHeight
[1] 480

$Info$EmbeddedImageType
[1] ""

$Info$EmbeddedImage
[1] "38325-"

$Info$ImageWidth
[1] 320

$Info$ImageHeight
[1] 240

$Info$EncodingProcess
[1] ""

$Info$BitsPerSample
[1] 8

$Info$ColorComponents
[1] 3

$Info$YCbCrSubSampling
[1] "4:2:022"

$Info$ImageSize
[1] 320240

$Info$Megapixels
[1] 0.077

$Info$PeakSpectralSensitivity
[1] 10.9

$Info$ShutterSpeed
[1] 150

$Info$ThumbnailImage
[1] "2474-"

$Info$FocalLength
[1] 1.8


$Dates
$Dates$FileModificationDateTime
[1] "2017-08-21 14:20:46"

$Dates$FileAccessDateTime
[1] "2017-10-04 02:36:24"

$Dates$FileInodeChangeDateTime
[1] "2017-09-10 18:41:44"

$Dates$ModifyDate
[1] "2017-08-21 08:20:46"

$Dates$CreateDate
[1] "2017-08-21 08:20:46"

$Dates$DateTimeOriginal
[1] "2017-08-21 16:20:46"
```

Is there a way to get the measurement i.e. spot value from the image? Or can I use exiftool to extract this value from the image and how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would try using exiftool on the command line rather than from the R package, Thermimage, since the R package does not report on all text output from exiftool.  Try this in a terminal window:

```
exiftool FLIR8655.jpg
```

which might yield something like this for your image:

```
...
Meas 1 Type                     : Spot
Meas 1 Params                   : 320 240
Meas 1 Label                    : 1
Meas 2 Type                     : Area
Meas 2 Params                   : 213 160 213 160
Meas 2 Label                    : 1
```

But I cannot find any output for the spot temperature (Meas 1 above) in the normal exiftool output.  You could export the raw thermal binary data with exiftool and extract the wth x hth data point corresponding to the spot position.